# не подставляется значение параметра в rewrite

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Проблемы с rewrite в nginx.

```
location ~ ^/inf/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$ {
    rewrite ^/inf/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$ /inf/inf.php?user=$1;
}
```

Почему то "args" пустой, т.е. "user=" и всё.

В чём может быть дело?

Comment: а что, по-вашему, должно туда попасть?

Comment: А где у вас группа захвата в регулярном выражении, которая бы подставлялась вместо `$1`?

Comment: ой.. что то я забыл.. в адресной строке я ввожу: `example.com/inf/test` в `args` вроде как должен попасть `test`.. или я что-то не понял... т.е. запрос выглядит так: `example.com/inf/inf.php?user=test`

Comment: Так может все-таки `rewrite ^/inf/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$ /inf/inf.php?user=$1;`?

Comment: спасибо Visman, заработало